# the last reducer is very slow in MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, reduce

the speed of the last reduce is very slow. the other reduce 
the number of my map and reduce is follows
the number of map is 18784, the number of reduce is 1500
the average of time for each reduce about 1'26, but the last reduce is about 2h
i try to change the number of reduce and reduce the size of job. but nothing changed

[the last reduce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbYvN.png)
as for my partition

```
public int getPartition(Object key, Object value, int numPartitions) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String keyStr = key.toString();
    int partId= String.valueOf(keyStr.hashCode()).hashCode();
    partId = Math.abs(partId % numPartitions);
    partId = Math.max(partId, 0);
    return partId;
    //return (key.hashCode() & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % numPartitions;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar experience, in my case it was due to only one reduce was doing processing all data. This happens due to data skewness. Take a look counters at reducers that is already been processed and the one that is taking lot of time, you will likely see more data is being handled by the reducer that is taking lot of time.

You might want to look into this.

[Hadoop handling data skew in reducer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32627836/hadoop-handling-data-skew-in-reducer)

Comment: thank you. but when i reduce the data size about 10% data and change my partitioner, and i get the same result. the last reduce is also slow.

Comment: Did you see how much data is it processing? Is it processing more data than rest of the reducers?

Comment: thank you.  And I find the reason. i forgot set the class of setCombinerClass

Answer (score 0):

Very probably you are facing skew data problem.

Or your keys are not very well distributed or your getPartition is generating the issue. Itś not clear form me why you are creating a string from the hash code of the string and then getting the hash code for this new string. My suggestion is that first try with the default partition and then look inside the distribution of your keys.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, when you process the large amount of data, you should set the class of Combiner. And if you want to changes encoding you should reset the Reduce function.
for example.

```
 public class GramModelReducer extends Reducer<Text, LongWritable, Text, LongWritable> {

private LongWritable result = new LongWritable();
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<LongWritable> values,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

      long sum = 0;
      for (LongWritable val : values) {
        sum += val.get();
      }
      result.set(sum);
      context.write(new Text(key.toString().getBytes("GB18030")), result);
}
```

}

```
class GramModelCombiner extends Reducer<Text, LongWritable, Text, LongWritable> {
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<LongWritable> values,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

      long sum = 0;
      for (LongWritable val : values) {
        sum += val.get();
      }
      context.write(key, new LongWritable(sum));
}
```

}